# Is there any equivalent of "whose" for "what" or "which"?

Tags: grammar

If I want to refer to a woman who has blue eyes, I can say "The woman *whose* eyes are blue". Is there a similar way to refer to a house, for example, that has blue door? "The house *??* door is blue".

I know there are some other ways to refer to the house, for example, "The house with the blue door", I am specifically curious about that particular way.

Comment: Why do you think "whose" cannot work in the "house" example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an equivalent.  In fact, it's as equivalent as they come.  It's...

*whose*

> **whose** adjective
>
> : of or relating to whom or which especially as possessor or possessors
>  
>   // *whose* gorgeous vesture heaps the ground
>   — Robert Browning
>
> , agent or agents
>   // the law courts, *whose* decisions were important
>   — F. L. Mott
>
> , or object or objects of an action
>   // the first poem whose *publication* he ever sanctioned— J. W. Krutch

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whose

You may think that because we don't say "the house who has a blue door," we can't say, "the house whose door is blue," but that isn't true. Non-living things can be modified by *whose*.